# Print header defined size string

Tags: c

I'm trying to print in a file a string with a fixed size. Something like this:

```
#define SIZE 30
main()
{
   FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.txt","w+");
   char s[10];
   sprintf(s, "my text");
   fprintf(fp, "%SIZEs", s);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

but I keep getting errors.. help?

Comment: Sure, a debugger will help. And reading the compiler errors (if any) would help too.

Comment: Actually, there are no compiling errors, but it doesn't print anything on the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define your format string like the following:

```
fprintf(fp, "%*s", SIZE, s);  // Right aligned string
fprintf(fp, "%-*s", SIZE, s); // Left aligned string
```

From the `printf` man page:

> **The precision**
>   Instead of a decimal digit string one may write `"*"` to specify that the precision is given in the next argument

Comment: That worked out, thanks a lot ^^

Comment: Even better: `fprintf(fp, "%" #SIZE "s", s);` to avoid wasting CPU cycles where the length is a compile-time constant.

Comment: @TimCooper Right, fixed.